# Django Error loading MySqlDB module

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new with Django and I follow a tuto. The problem is that the tuto uses Sqlite but I want to use MySql server instead. I changed the parameters following documentation but I have the following error when I try to run the server. I already found some resolve but it didn't work...

For your information, I installed MySql-Python and reinstall Django with PIP. Without any success. I hope you will be able to help me.

Traceback :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\adescamp>cd C:\Users\adescamp\agregmail

C:\Users\adescamp\agregmail>python manage.py runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
translation.activate('en-us')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
return _trans.activate(language)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
_active.value = translation(language)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
app = import_module(appname)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 48, in <module>
class Permission(models.Model):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 96, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you install `python-MySQLdb`

Comment: I just tried. But pip doesn't find any distribution for python-mysqldb.

Comment: can you try `mysql-python`

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to import or execute mysql-python in python and in shell but it doesn't work.

Comment: pip install `mysql-python`

Comment: Ok... Sorry. I got the point. Pip install mysql-python doesn't work due to problem with vcvarsall.bat
I will check further on this problem. Sorry.

Comment: I found the solution!

I had to install mysql-python. Easy but: don't do that with PIP because it won't work. You have to install mysql-python with easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I had to install mysql-python. Easy but: don't do that with PIP because it won't work. You have to install mysql-p

Answer (score 0):

as you are running python on windows. Pip install mysql-python won't work. Try using python-mysql from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python